# Investigation of JavaScript isocontouring algorithm performance

Tags: javascript, performance, benchmarking

I want to investigate JavaScript isocontouring algorithm performance. I repeated one sampl for one thousand times. Average time is nearly 2 ms. But first time is nearly 100 ms. What is this? Is this difference arise from optimization? Can I investigate JavaScript algorithms performance in this way? JavaScript was 'in Browser'.

Comment: https://mrale.ph/blog/2012/12/15/microbenchmarks-fairy-tale.html

Comment: This article is helpful. But what I may do for compare algorithms in JavaScript?

Comment: As I see in [eval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) "eval() is also slower than the alternatives, since it has to invoke the JS interpreter, while many other constructs are optimized by modern JS engines." That is, eval(), maybe, dont use optimization.

Comment: No, it depends on what the `eval` code does. If you are just creating a *self-contained* function or object structure, optimisations to it are applied as normal (as if the structure was created in a standalone `<script>`). What is slow however is when the `eval` code tries to access information from the scope where `eval(…)` was called - it's not possible to optimise the scope structure of code containing such an `eval(…)` call because the engine has to be able to cope with it doing *anything*. So you should always use `new Function` or indirect eval, which inherently prevent such dependencies